# How to add the cycle plugin?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to add the "cycle" plugin in my faq page. I just want to have the paragraph have a fade effect. IT looks like the plugin only takes classes so i made my div to a .test and i still do not get any effects. any suggestions?

The cycle plugin has code like this:

```
$('.slideshow').cycle({ 
    fx: 'scrollDown' 
    speed:    300, 
    timeout:  2000
});
```

I am trying to put the code above in my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">

    <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Assignment FAQs</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>

    <style>

    /* type selectors */

    article, aside, figure, figcaption, footer, header, nav, section {

        display: block;

    }

    * {

        margin: 0;

        padding: 0;

    }

    h2{

    font-size:25px;

    margin-bottom:0px;

    cursor:pointer;

    text-indent:20px;

    }



    div{
    margin-bottom:25px;
    }

    .img_plus{
    background-image: url(plus.png);
    background-position: left center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    }

    .img_minus{

    background-image: url(minus.png);
    background-position: left center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    }

    .hide{

    display:none;

    }

      .effect {color: red;}

    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>



    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("div").addClass("hide");

    $('h2').addClass('img_plus');


        $('h2').click(function() {

        //add the class re move the class.

                    // "this" method means what ever h2 was clocked on

                    //this over rides the image plus. if u click first time, add image plus then second we are remvong

                    //toggle class means add the class remove the class.

                    //first time add class. minus backorund overides plus backgorund.

            $(this).toggleClass('img_minus');

            $(this).next('div').toggleClass('hide');

        });//ends click

                    // hover is built in method.

        $('h2').hover(

          function(){

          $(this).addClass('effect');

          }, //end mouseover

         function(){

          $(this).removeClass('effect');

          } //end mouse     

       ); //end hover

        }); //ends ready

    </script>

    </head>



    <body>

        <p> this is a DEMO FAQ

    <ul>

    <li> change the background plus and minus </li>

    <li> same thing here do some more </li>

    </p>

    </ul>
    <h1> FAQ -Click this to see </h1>
    <h2> what is jQuery </h2>
    <div class = "test"> tjQuery is a fast, small, and feature-rich JavaScript library. It makes things like HTML document traversal and manipulation, event handling, animation, and Ajax much simpler with an easy-to-use API that works across a multitude of browsers.</div>
    <h2> why is jQuery becoming popular? </h2>
    <div> Mission and philosophy: jQuery set out to make DOM manipulation easier to use, and had a single minded focus on achieving that goal. Other frameworks like Mootools and Dojo focused on making it easier to create complex applications, an idea that was ahead of its time (in 2007), and split the attention of the community and created unnecessary complexity for 99% of developers

    who are not interested in complex applications or advance javascript</div>
         <h2> What is harder. JS or jQuery  </h2>

        <div> JS </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Remove the unclosed `<script type="text/javascript">` tag

Answer (score 0):

On each `<h2>` tag before the text appears, add `onclick="fadeText(this)"`. Then add this function to your javascript.

```
function fadeText(dom) {
$(dom).next().fadeIn();
}
```